# What Apache mod_log_forensic is used for?

Tags: apache-http-server

Can anybody explain in plain English what Apache [`mod_log_forensic`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_forensic.html) module exactly does, and what are the benefits of using it on the web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module adds in the log for each client request an ID called  forensic-id that looks like this: `+q6VxwcCbAQNAAEqfC5MAVADC` .

When the request is completed adds a line with the same *ID*, something like this:

`-q6VxwcCbAQNAAEqfC5MAVADC*`.

It helps to find incorrect requests, just find the ID starting with **+** and then look for the same ID with **-**. If it never appears you are having incomplete requests.

This module usually breaks other applications that read the Apache logs, so is used only for debugging purposes.